# Call SQL Functions after PIVOT

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure that's taking a very long time because I have 2 function calls that are being called before a PIVOT, which means it's calling the functions 5 times for each record rather than once for each record.  How can I get rewrite my query so that the 2 function calls right at the end of the query are run after the Pivot rather than before?

Here's the query

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
ServiceRecordID INT,
LocationStd VARCHAR(1000),
AreaServedStd VARCHAR(1000),
RegionalLimited BIT,
Region VARCHAR(255),
Visible BIT
)

DECLARE @RegionCount INT

SELECT @RegionCount = COUNT(RegionID) FROM Regions WHERE SiteID = @SiteID AND RegionID % 100 != 0

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT TOP (@RegionCount * 100) SR.ServiceRecordID, SR.LocationStd, SR.AreaServedStd, SR.RegionalLimited, R.Region,
        CASE WHEN (ISNULL(R_SR.RegionID,0) = 0 AND ISNULL(R_SR_Serv.RegionID,0) = 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Visible
FROM ServiceRecord SR
INNER JOIN Sites S ON SR.SiteID = S.SiteID
INNER JOIN Regions R ON R.SiteID = S.SiteID
LEFT OUTER JOIN lkup_Region_ServiceRecord R_SR ON R_SR.RegionID = R.RegionID AND R_SR.ServiceRecordID = SR.ServiceRecordID
LEFT OUTER JOIN lkup_Region_ServiceRecord_Serv R_SR_Serv ON R_SR_Serv.RegionID = R.RegionID AND R_SR_Serv.ServiceRecordID = SR.ServiceRecordID AND SR.RegionalLimited = 0
WHERE SR.SiteID = @SiteID
AND R.RegionID % 100 != 0
ORDER BY SR.ServiceRecordID

DECLARE @RegionList varchar(2000),@SQL varchar(max)
SELECT @RegionList = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + Region + ']' FROM #Temp ORDER BY ',[' + Region + ']' FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT ServiceRecordID,
dbo.fn_ServiceRecordGetServiceName(ServiceRecordID,'''') AS ServiceName,
LocationStd,
AreaServedStd,
RegionalLimited, 
Region As Region,
dbo.fn_GetOtherRegionalSitesForServiceRecord(ServiceRecordID) AS OtherSites,
CAST(Visible AS INT) AS Visible FROM #Temp) B PIVOT(MAX(Visible) FOR Region IN (' + @RegionList + ')) A'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Yes you should be able to replace the `select *` with the actual column names and you can use apply the function to the columns.

Comment: Simplification suggestion: `CASE WHEN R_SR.RegionID <> 0 AND R_SR_Serv.RegionID <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Visible`

Comment: thanks bluefeet, not sure I follow.  I have the columns being selected individually already don't I?

Comment: @MarkHighfield No your final select is using `select *`, change that to `select col1, col2, col3`, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the function calls after the PIVOT:

```
SET @SQL='
SELECT
   A.*,
   N.ServiceName,
   S.OtherSites
FROM 
   (
      SELECT
         ServiceRecordID,
         LocationStd,
         AreaServedStd,
         RegionalLimited, 
         Region,
         CAST(Visible AS INT) AS Visible
      FROM #Temp
   ) B
   PIVOT(MAX(Visible) FOR Region IN (' + @RegionList + ')) A
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT dbo.fn_ServiceRecordGetServiceName(A.ServiceRecordID,'''')
   ) N (ServiceName)
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT dbo.fn_GetOtherRegionalSitesForServiceRecord(A.ServiceRecordID)
   ) S (OtherSites);
';
```

Or just put them in the outer SELECT:

```
SET @SQL='
SELECT
   A.*,
   ServiceName = dbo.fn_ServiceRecordGetServiceName(A.ServiceRecordID,''''),
   OtherSites = dbo.fn_GetOtherRegionalSitesForServiceRecord(A.ServiceRecordID)
FROM 
   (
      SELECT
         ServiceRecordID,
         LocationStd,
         AreaServedStd,
         RegionalLimited, 
         Region,
         CAST(Visible AS INT) AS Visible
      FROM #Temp
   ) B
   PIVOT(MAX(Visible) FOR Region IN (' + @RegionList + ')) A
';
```

If you can possibly convert those functions to be table-valued rowset-returning consisting of a single SELECT statement, you may get a huge performance improvement as well.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_ServiceRecordGetServiceName2(
   @ServiceRecordID itn
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN ( -- single select statement
   SELECT ServiceName = Blah
   FROM dbo.Gorp
   WHERE Gunk = 'Ralph'
);
```

Then

```
OUTER APPLY dbo.fn_ServiceRecordGetServiceName(ServiceRecordID,'''') N
```

And `N.ServiceName` will return the value(s).

Also, it is not correct to tack on square brackets to convert data values to valid `sysname`s. You should use the `QuoteName` function. This will ensure your system doesn't break no matter WHAT crazy value is entered 13 years from now (think `'Taiwan [North]'`):

```
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QuoteName(Region) FROM #Temp ...
```

Note:

Since you said that this is for display in a web page, you don't even need to do the pivoting on the server. Instead, return 2 rowsets to the client, one with the Site data and one with the column data for the Regions. You *would* need an additional pass through every row in the `Region` rowset to find out all the regions needed, but this can be done very quickly. Finally, adjust your program code to step through the Region rows as needed for each matching Site, and created your output.

One reason this is worth the investment is that if your application grows in size, you can always throw another web server at the problem, but it's a *lot* harder to throw another database at it. A new web server will cost less than continually beefing up your SQL Server.

P.S. Even dynamic SQL is easier to deal with when you format it well. :)

Comment: wow thanks a ton! That worked and cut the time by 300% or more!  Both functions return Varchar(max) values in the format I need them displayed on the webpage.  How would I display them correctly if they returned in table-valued rowset format?

Comment: It would work exactly the same. The difference is that the table-valued function returns a rowset, instead of a value. I've shown you how to deal with that with the standalone `OUTER APPLY` line above.